# Determinant of solution matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

Let $\phi(t)$ be a solution matrix.  Show that $$\det\phi(t)=\det\phi(t)\exp\int_{t_0}^t\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds.$$

I know that $[\det\phi(t)]'=\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(t)\det\phi(t),$ but I am not how to use this fact and how to move on from here.

Comment: $\phi$ is a solution to what?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that (known as Abel's equation)
$$
\big(\det\phi(t)\big)'=\Big(\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(t)\Big)\det\phi(t),
$$
multiply both sides by $\exp\left(-\int_{t_0}^t\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds\right)$ and obtain
$$
\exp\Big(-\int_{t_0}^t\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds\Big)\big(\det\phi(t)\big)'=
\exp\Big(-\int_{t_0}^t\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds\Big)\Big(\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(t)\Big)\det\phi(t),
$$
or
$$
\exp\Big(-\int_{t_0}^t\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds\Big)\left(\big(\det\phi(t)\big)'-\Big(\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(t)\Big)\det\phi(t)\right)=0,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\left(\exp\Big(-\int_{t_0}^t\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds\Big)\,\det\phi(t)\right)'=0,
$$
which means that the function $$f(t)=\exp\Big(-\int_{t_0}^t\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds\Big)\,\det\phi(t),$$ is constant, and hence
$$
\exp\Big(-\int_{t_0}^t\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds\Big)\,\det\phi(t)=\exp\Big(-\int_{t_0}^{t_0}\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds\Big)\,\det\phi(t_0)=\det\phi(t_0),
$$
and finally we get that
$$
\det\phi(t)=\det\phi(t_0)\,\exp\Big(\int_{t_0}^t\sum_{j=1}^na_{jj}(s)\,ds\Big).
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{[\det \phi(t)]'}{\det \phi(t)} = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{jj}(s) \implies\\
\int_{t_0}^t\frac{[\det \phi(t)]'}{\det \phi(t)}dt = 
\int_{t_0}^t\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{jj}(s)\right)dt
$$

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that $\phi$ solves $\dot{\phi}(t) = A(t) \phi(t)$ subject to the solution passing through $\phi(t_0)$ at time $t_0$.

This is known as Liouville's formula, another proof may be found at
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula).

A standard result is that if $f(A) = \det A$, then $Df(A) (\Delta) = \det A \operatorname{tr} (A^{-1} \Delta)$.

Now let $\delta(t) = \det \phi(t) = (f \circ \phi)(t)$, then we have 
$\dot{\delta}(t) = D \delta(t) = D(f \circ \phi)(t) = D f(\phi(t)) D \phi(t)$, hence  we have
$\dot{\delta}(t) = \delta(t) \operatorname{tr} (\phi(t)^{-1} \dot{\phi}(t)) = \delta(t) \operatorname{tr} A(t)$.

It is straightforward to solve this first order linear ODE using the integrating factor $t \mapsto e^{-\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \operatorname{tr} A(s) ds} $ to get the unique solution
 $\delta(t) = \delta(t_0) e^{\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \operatorname{tr} A(s) ds} $. Or, in other words,
$\det \phi(t) = \det \phi(t_0) e^{\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \operatorname{tr} A(s) ds} $.